# Add text after price unless the price is zero, then Call for price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

1. I have products with prices that need to all end with "per sq. ft." I want this to only apply to products of a particular category and only when the price is greater than 0.
2. When the product has no price listed I need the price to say "Call for Price" without the square footage text after it.

So here is a start I found online but they dont have any conditions associated with them so they apply to all product all the time.

```
/* Display "Call for Price" instead of empty price */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
function custom_price_message( $price ) {
    $vat = ' per sq. ft.';
    return $price . $vat;
}

/* Display "Call for Price" instead of empty price */
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');
function custom_call_for_price() {
     return 'Call for Price';
}
```

Comment: Another sweet thing would be to have the "call for price" text be a clickable "tel" link that would call once clicked. This is not necessary but just a bonus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
function custom_price_message($price) {
 if(!empty($price)){
   $vat = 'Your Text Here';
   return $price . $vat;
 }else{
   return 'CALL FOR PRICE';
 }
}
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a step in the right direction but I just need to add a condition now to make this only apply to a certain product category.

Comment: I voted but my reputation is below 15 (new account) so it wont be visible until its higher

Comment: Hehehe okay  don't forget in future 

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for the help. I used both of your code strings and here is what i came up with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );

function custom_price_message($price) {

if ( !has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
   return $price;

} elseif (!empty($price)){
   $vat = ' per ft<sup>2</sup>';
   return $price . $vat;

 }else{
   return 'Call for Price';
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bump this post. I have been struggling for hours trying to figure out how to change the code above to apply to multiple terms. I want the same rules to apply to another product category "remnants" as well as "stones". Any help would be aweome!